# select best attribute of a row SQL oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

```
   YEAR    MONTH    BALANCE   SSN
  2016          1       3175 34/1043/03T
  2016          1       2984 93/1194/07T
  2016          1       2269 39/3149/00T
  2015         12       3172 36/1011/03T
  2015         12       2984 22/1224/07T
  2015         12       2169 12/3143/00T
```

For example I have this table, but I have rows for each month of each year, and I have to choose the best ssn and balance of each month of each year. For example, here, I would like obtain this on my query:

```
   YEAR    MONTH    BALANCE   SSN
  2016          1       3175 34/1043/03T
  2015         12       3172 36/1011/03T
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in several ways.  A very Oracle'ish way is to use `keep`:

```
select year, month,
       max(balance) as balance,
       max(SSN) keep (dense_rank first order by balance desc) as ssn
from t
group by year, month;
```

Answer (score 0):

Like most DBMSes Oracle supports `ROW_NUMBER`/`RANK`:

```
select *
from
 (
   select year, month, balance, SSN,
      row_number() 
      over (partition by year, month
            order by balance desc) as rn
   from tab
 ) dt
where rn = 1
```